# Gradle build fails when using capacitor-image-crop plugin

Tags: angular, gradle, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to replace a deprecated plugin ( [cordova-plugin-crop](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop) ) with a plugin that is not official but is more recent  [capacitor-image-crop](https://github.com/TeamHive/capacitor-image-crop) but when I try to run the project on android studio it gives me this error `Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/ionic-team/capacitor/ionic-team/capacitor-android/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project`

Already tried: Disabling gradle offline mode and syncing the projec, removing android platform, updating gradle, [this is not my case](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/4542). nothing seems to work.

some info

```
Gradle version: 5.6.4

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.3 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1101.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.1.4
   @angular/cli                  : 11.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 2.4.7
   @capacitor/android : 2.4.7
   @capacitor/core    : 2.4.7
   @capacitor/ios     : 2.4.7

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.4.0

System:

   NodeJS : v14.17.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.13
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: `jcenter()` has been shut down by JFrog https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown . Somewhere in your build, you must have `https://dl.bintray.com/ionic-team` as a repository, and this needs removing as it says in the issue you linked to 

Comment: I'm not finding much, I tried to look in all build.gradle files and to search globally in the project but I can't find anything the some references in a jarRepositories.xml file that I have already commented with no result

Comment: Ok, I found the build.gradle like the issue that I linked and delete the line and now I have another error that says  `Could not find any matches for ionic-team:capacitor-android:1+ as no versions of ionic-team:capacitor-android are available.`

Comment: I wonder if they published anywhere after jcenter shut down 

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error :
Could not find any matches for ionic-team:capacitor-android:1+ as no versions of ionic-team:capacitor-android are available.

change  : implementation 'ionic-team:capacitor-android:1+'
to this : implementation project(':capacitor-android')

Comment: Thanks for the reply, at the end I gave up on using this plugin but I will probably try again because the official one looks really old.